# How to Reference XML File/Data to be Used with HTML and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

So I have an XML file, that I generated from an Excel file. Each item looks like this:

```
<item>
    <partnum>pn0001</partnum>
    <category>Parent Category</category>
    <title>Item Name Here</title>
    <type>T27</type>
    <diameter>6"</diameter>
    <width>0.045"</width>
    <arbor>7/8"</arbor>
    <material>Metal</material>
    <maxrpm>13300</maxrpm>
    <tool>Angle Grinder</tool>
    <purpose>Cutting</purpose>
    <brand>Brand Name Here</brand>
    <imgsrc>localfolder\file.jpg</imgsrc>
</item>
```

I'd like to be able to reference this data, and create variables for each of the items. Obviously, I'll have to write a loop that will go through each item, and store the data. It will end up being something like pn0001.category, pn0001.title. etc, etc.

My question is: how do I begin to reference the XML file? I ran across this link: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Which is great, but in the code, you'll see that they have the XML data hard-coded as a string in the first variable.

Basically, **how do I get the data from the XML into variables in either Javascript or jQuery?**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jquery example

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><items><item><partnum>pn0001</partnum><type>T27</type><material>Metal</material></item><item><partnum>pn0002</partnum><type>T28</type><material>plastic</material></item></items>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

$xml.find('item').each(function(index) {
  var partnum = $(this).find('partnum').text();
  var type = $(this).find('type').text();
  var material = $(this).find('material').text();

  $('<span>' + partnum + ' ' + type + ' ' + material + '</span><br>').appendTo('#output');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This is great. However, do I have to paste the raw XML into the quotations of the variable xml? Or can I reference the individual file? I'd like to be able to reuse the code as much as I can, as I am going to have several XML files. EDIT: The file is stored locally in an adjacent folder.

Comment: You should reference the XML file. The `xml` variable containing the string XML code was just an example.